# I'm new at javascript and i don't know why it wont jump to the else statment

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I'm new to Javascript and I learned everything I know off some site. So I don't know if I'm using an old version of Javascript or if there was some code from other software in there like jQuery. All I know is that my code doesn't want to go to the else statement.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<center>
        <script>

confirm("Are you ready to play!");
var age = prompt("What/'s your age?");
if(age <= 18)
{
    document.write("you may play However i take no responsibility for your actions");
}
else
{
    document.write("Go ahead but your of age!");
}

document.write("Snow White and Batman were hanging out at the bus stop, waiting to go to the shops. There was a sale on and both needed some new threads. You've never really liked Batman. You walk up to him.");
document.write("Batman glares at you.");
var userAnswer = prompt('Are you feeling lucky, punk?');

if (userAnswer = "yes")
{
    document.write("Batman hits you very hard. It's Batman and you're you! Of course Batman wins!");
}
else
{
    document.write("You did not say yes to feeling lucky. Good choice! You are a winner in the game of not getting beaten up by Batman.");
}

var feedback = prompt("how good was the game out of 10?");

if (feedback >= 8)
{
    document.write ("This is just the beginning of my game empire. Stay tuned for more!");
}
else
{
    document.write("I slaved away at this game and you gave me that score?! The nerve! Just you wait!");
}

</script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the site says to use `document.write()`, it is indeed an old site. That's an obsolete way for javascript to update the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Else statement not executed javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483444/else-statement-not-executed-javascript)

Answer (score 8):

`=` is an *assignment* and will be true if you are assigning a true value. You want an (strict) [equality test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators): `===` (or `==`)

Answer (score 0):

Use == instead of =.

Anyways, you should check out https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-and-operator-in-javascript and other sites about = and == and ===.

Second, document.write, deletes the whole document and replaces it with text. If you don't want to delete the whole document, make a division called:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='gameText'>
    Are you ready to play?
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, since you are new to javascript, I'll explain what it does.

The  tag stands for division, it's just basically a section.

The id part names the section with gameText.

It's simple HTML, this just in psuedocode form mean:

> Create new section in the HTML document with the name of gameText

As for the javascript, instead of doing document write, you should use the innerHTML tag to only affect the section.

Use javascript to get the name or id of the section and change the innerHTML of it.

The code should look like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>

    confirm("Are you ready to play!");
    var age = prompt("What/'s your age?");
    if(age <= 18){
        document.getElementById('gameText').innerHTML = "you may play However i take no responsibility for your actions";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('gameText').innerHTML = "Go ahead but you're of age!";
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='gameText'>
    Are you ready to play?
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Additionally, please fix your spelling errors please. I can clearly see that you are trying to create a HTML/JS game which you're going to publish somewhere, or you are just making it for fun.

Either way, no one will play your game if it has grammar and spelling mistakes.

All of this bit, a bit of the above and below are just ways to help you improve this alright?

Well anyways, instead of having your game automatically run when you load the HTML document, you really should have a button that starts the game, so nobody gets annoyed with the popups when you enter the page.

Comment: Made 4 edits to this post. Gave more feedback and helpful things about fixing this html document.